# Converting javascript key value pair object to a java key value pair.

Tags: java, javascript

I have a javascript array containing an object which represents a key value pair. I'm trying to convert this javascript object into a java object. Could someone assist me? Thanks in advance.

Javascript

```
var array = [];        

for (var i = 0; i < filterIdArray.length; i++) {
    array.push({name:filterIdArray[i], value:$("#" + filterIdArray[i]).val()});
}

params["t:array"] = array;
```

Java

```
@RequestParameter(value = "t:array", allowBlank = true) String array

List<String> inputs = null;

if(array != null) {
    inputs = Arrays.asList(array);
}
```

Java Object representing key value pair

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public Test() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.  Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I'm sorry, that title was a cache from an old question. I have a javascript key value pair that I'm putting into an array. I'm trying to pass the javascript array back to my java object then iterate the array and more or less cast my key value pair object to my Test object. I just want to convert my key value pair in javascript to a key value pair on java. Perhaps a java hashmap would be better than my Test object.

Comment: So you're passing a string to java of json content (javascript array). Please look at JSON parsing libraries like GSON or json.org.

Comment: @TJR but is that json I'm creating in js?

Comment: The form data would be transmitted as a string. So this wouldn't do what you're expecting it to do. What you want is to set the form value to JSON.stringify(array). Then that could be parsed on the backend.